# div background color won't fill the div

Tags: css, background-color

For some reason I cannot for the lie of me figure out why the background color of a div doesn't fill. I have 3 images in the div. but the color only comes down a little ways. I cannot find a previous post that gives me the answer.

```css
#RevWrapper {
 clear: both;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 1232px;
 display: block;
 padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
 padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
 background-color: #006666;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
}
#rev1 {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
#rev2 {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
#rev3 {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
.revimagecenter {    
    display: block;
 width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="RevWrapper">
    <div id="rev1"><img src="images/rev1.fw.png" alt="Review 1" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
    <div id="rev2"><img src="images/rev2.fw.png" alt="Review 2" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
    <div id="rev3"><img src="images/rev3.fw.png" alt="Review 3" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's due to the floats - they are not "covered" by surrounding parent elements. Add `overflow: auto;` to the wrapper to change this behaviour:

```css
#RevWrapper {
 clear: both;
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 1232px;
 display: block;
 padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
 padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
 background-color: #006666;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#rev1 {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
#rev2 {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
#rev3 {
 clear: none;
 float: left;
 width: 33.3%;
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}
.revimagecenter {    
    display: block;
 width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="RevWrapper">
    <div id="rev1"><img src="images/rev1.fw.png" alt="Review 1" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
    <div id="rev2"><img src="images/rev2.fw.png" alt="Review 2" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
    <div id="rev3"><img src="images/rev3.fw.png" alt="Review 3" class="revimagecenter">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is your answer!  Sadly @Johannes beat me to it :P

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have used `float`. In this case, remove `float` and `clear` from all and rather than using `float`, you can try `margin-left` for second and third divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
#RevWrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1232px;
    display: block;
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1232px)/2);
    background-color: #006666;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
#rev1 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    display: block;
}
#rev2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    display: block;
}
#rev3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    display: block;
}
.revimagecenter {    
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

Remove the padding.
```

Comment: thanks it works great..

Comment: You're welcome! you can approve my answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` as the last div inside RevWrapper.

Comment: Looks like there are several answers to this